# Update value in a recursive type - elm lang

Tags: recursion, elm

I have a tree like structure of text nodes that might have another text nodes as children, and I need to update one value in it. What's the easiest way to update text node that's somewhere deep in that tree (or it is not in that tree at all)?

In a non-immutable language, I would simply change a value of that item, and that's it, but it's quite tricky in an immutable language like Elm.

```
type alias Item =
  { id: String
  , text: String
  , children: ChildItems
  }

type ChildItems = ChildItems (List Item)

type alias Model =
  { rootItem: Item
  }

updateItem: Item -> Item -> Item
updateItem: rootItem item =
   -- TODO

...

update model =
  case msg of
    UpdateItem item updatedText ->
      let
        updatedItem = { item | text = updatedText }
      in
        ({ model | rootItem = (updateItem model.rootItem updatedItem) }, Cmd.none)
```

this is what I came up with

```
updateItem: Item.Item -> Item.Item -> Item.Item
updateItem rootItem updatedItem =
  if rootItem.id == updatedItem.id then
    updatedItem
  else
    case rootItem.children of
      Item.ChildItem [] ->
        rootItem

      Item.ChildItem children ->
        let
          updatedChildren =
            case children of
              [] ->
                []

              children ->
                List.map (\item ->
                  updateItem rootItem item) children
        in
          { rootItem | children = Item.ChildItem updatedChildren }
```

but I'm getting an `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error

Comment: On data manipulation patterns I highly recommend to check Haskell resources. Elm syntax is very close to that of Haskell and the Haskell community has devoted huge amounts of time on these matters.

Look for higher order functions and functors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason you're getting the stack overflow is because you are returning `rootItem` instead of `[]` in the `Item.ChildItems []` case.

I'm going to modify your code a bit because there are some common patterns we can pull out. First off, let's take the underlying tree-ish structure and make that more generic so that it could fit any type of thing, not just `Item`:

```elm
type Node a
  = Node a (List (Node a))
```

That gives us a structure that always has a root node and may have any number of children, each of who may also have any number of children.

If we think about the algorithm you were going for, we can extrapolate a familiar pattern. You have a structure with multiple items and you want an algorithm that visits each item and optionally changes it. That sounds a lot like `List.map`. It's such a common idiom that it's a good idea to call our generalized function `map`:

```elm
map : (a -> b) -> Node a -> Node b
map f (Node item children) =
  Node (f item) (List.map (map f) children)
```

*(Side note:  We've just stumbled into [functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor)!)*

Since I've taken the idea of children and placed it into the `Node` type, we need to modify the alias `Item` like so:

```elm
type alias Item =
  { id: String
  , text: String
  }
```

Now that we have an `Item`, it will be helpful to have a function that can update it if the `id` matches a certain value. Since in the future, you may have more update functions you want to perform, it's best to keep the lookup and ID matching portion separate from the function you actually want to perform:

```elm
updateByID : String -> (Item -> Item) -> Item -> Item
updateByID id f item =
  if item.id == id then
    f item
  else
    item
```

Now to perform an update on an item matching the id, anywhere within the tree, you can simply do this:

```elm
map (updateByID "someID" (\x -> { x | text = "Woohoo!" })) rootNode
```

Comment: Excellent answer! You've made my day :)

Comment: How would I update the nested list of Items using this pattern?

The problem I'm hitting is that the record update expression is designed to be the return expression of any function it appears in.I n a function designed to create a new Item, the return expression should be the new item, not the item's parent's list of children, which is what I need to update.

Do we have scripture on how to deal with recursive (aka "tree") structures? I've seen instructions on making the item a type alias and the collection a type; you offer a different protocol.

Comment: @RichardHaven that is handled by the map function - notice that in its body it creates a Node made up of the item from the Node it was given, possibly modified by the function, and the children from the Node it was given, each also possibly modified by the function. Ultimately when feeding updateById into map it will recursively build up the tree of nodes using the same pieces, except for the one item that has been changed.

Comment: What an absolutely awesome answer.